# -[__NSCFString objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: iphone

I have little problem in my iPhone application code but can not identify. please help.

bellow is my code gives me error.

this code is in loop.

```
- (void)playSoundSequence{     
if(songCounter >= totalSoundsInQueue || songCounter < 0){
    songCounter = 0;
}
NSLog(@"%d", songCounter);
sound = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", [theSoundArray objectAtIndex:songCounter]];
NSLog(@"call");
audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:sound ofType:@""]] error:NULL];
sound =  nil;
[sound release];
audioPlayer.delegate = self;
audioPlayer.volume = m_volSlider.value;
[audioPlayer play];
m_progressBar.progress = 0;
m_progressSlider.value = 0;
m_progressSlider.maximumValue = audioPlayer.duration;
[m_btnPlay setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pause.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
bgTaskId = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:NULL];
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(updateDisplay) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
songCounter++;
}
```

`songCounter` is integer and one by one increment according to loop.

In this code `theSoundArray` is my array that contain like bellow

```
"song1.mp3",
"song2.mp3",
"song3.mp3",
"song4.mp3"
```

The problem is whenever first time my loop was called and "songCounter" was 0 it's run fine. Then 2nd time goes in loop and "songCounter" was 1 then there have problem and gives me error.

Below is the error.

```
-[__NSCFString objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

Comment: Please show code for how you create `theSoundArray`.

Comment: NSString *bundleRoot = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
    NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSArray *dirContents = [fm contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:bundleRoot error:nil];
    NSPredicate *fltr = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self ENDSWITH '.mp3'"];
    theSoundArray = [dirContents filteredArrayUsingPredicate:fltr];

Comment: i fetched all file from my directory and it's generate an Array.

Comment: Where you are initializing the array and where the loop exists?

Comment: You must be doing something more with `theSoundArray`. The error shows it's an `NSString` at that point.

Comment: @ mattjgalloway


NSLog(@"%d", songCounter);
    sound = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", [theSoundArray objectAtIndex:songCounter]];
    NSLog(@"call");
    audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:sound ofType:@""]] error:NULL];
    sound =  nil;
    [sound release];
    audioPlayer.delegate = self;
    audioPlayer.volume = m_volSlider.value;
    [audioPlayer play];

Comment: Write the loop code for more help.

Comment: this is my further code. when song is finish it again call this code with increment of "songCounter".

Comment: Are you using ARC in your project

Comment: Instead of 
theSoundArray = [dirContents filteredArrayUsingPredicate:fltr]; 
usetheSoundArray =[[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:[dirContents filteredArrayUsingPredicate:fltr]];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope you have not retained the array , and so when you are accessing that after some time, it crashes.

So, do as following while initializing the `theSoundArray`. See the `retain`

```
NSString *bundleRoot = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]; 
NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager]; 
NSArray *dirContents = [fm contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:bundleRoot error:nil]; 
NSPredicate *fltr = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self ENDSWITH '.mp3'"]; 
theSoundArray = [[dirContents filteredArrayUsingPredicate:fltr] retain];
```

And try now.

**EDIT**

And the order is not correct in the following statements.

```
sound =  nil;
[sound release];
```

You release it and then set it to nil.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `retain` `theSoundArray` for the duration you need it, and then `release` it afterward. It's getting deallocated and a string is taking up residence at its old address.

If you're using ARC, this should not apply. :)